# Do there exist irreducible elements in this domain?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, factorization, unique-factorization-domains

I asked [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4176670/how-to-check-whether-an-element-in-this-domain-is-irreducible-or-not) question on MSE. Here also I have the same motive in the question.

Let $D= \{\,a_1x^{r_1} + \cdots + a_n x^{r_n} \, \vert  \, a_i \in \mathbb{C} \text{ for } i= 1,2,\dots,n \text{ and each $r_i$ is a real number such that } 0 \le r_1 < r_2 < \cdots <r_n   \,\}$

Given non zero, non unit element $f(x) = a_1x^{r_1} + \cdots + a_n x^{r_n}$ in $D$, if all of $r_i$ are rationals then we can find an integer $s$ such that $f(x^s) \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ and we can split $f(x^s)$ into linear factors in $\mathbb{C}[x]$ by which it follows that there exist a complex number $b$ such that $x^{\frac1s} - b $ divides $f(x)$. Since $x^{\frac1s} - b$ can be written as product of elements which are not unit, $f(x)$ cannot be an irreducible. Moreover this argument shows that $f(x)$ cannot be written as finite product of irreducibles.

In general, the above strategy works if we can find an integer $s$ such that $sr_i \in \mathbb{Q}$ for all $i$ then $f(x)$ cannot be written as a finite product of irreducibles.

Difficulties come in simplest cases such as $g(x) = 1 + x^e + x^{\pi}$ in which I failed to deduce whether this is irreducible or not. Are there any methods to check the reducibility of an element in $D$? This $D$ is certainly not a factorization domain but the stronger statement would be to check if all the non-zero , non-unit elements are reducible?

Comment: This is the group algebra $\mathbf{C}[\mathbf{R}]$.

Comment: $1+x^e+x^\pi$ is not really a great test choice since one doesn't know whether $(1,\pi,e)$ is linearly $\mathbf{Q}$-free. But studying $1+x^a+x^b$ with $(1,a,b)$ with $(1,a,b)$ linearly $\mathbf{Q}$-free is reasonable instead.

Comment: And if I'm correct, it's irreducible iff $1+x^n+y^m$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{C}[x,y]$ for all $n,m\ge 1$.

Comment: @ YCor I am unfamiliar with the word linearly Q free. Does that mean $1,a,b$ are linearly independent vectors in the vector space $\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @ YCor I did not understand your last comment.

Comment: @ YCor I am not very familiar with group algebras. I thought of this question while I was studying factorization domains.

Comment: It is not a group algebra because the exponents are nonnegative.

Comment: Yes, it's a semigroup algebra, but here switching from polynomials to Laurent polynomials is straightforward. I wrote an extended comment as an answer to explain the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix $m\ge 0$. Let $a_1,\dots,a_m\in\mathbf{R}$ be linearly independent over $\mathbf{Q}$.

**Claim** The element $1+\sum_{i=1}^mx^{a_i}$ is irreducible in $D=\mathbf{C}[\mathbf{R}_{\ge 0}]$ iff for all integers $n_1,\dots n_m\ge 1$, the polynomial $1+\sum_{i=1}^mz_i^{n_i}$ is irreducible in the polynomial algebra $\mathbf{C}[z_1,\dots,z_m]\,(=\mathbf{C}[\mathbf{N}^m])$.

Proof: one direction is straightforward: if $1+\sum_{i=1}^m{z_i^{n_i}}$ is not irreducible in $\mathbf{C}[z_1,\dots,z_m]$ we mechanically inherit such a factorization in $D$.

Conversely, suppose that $1+\sum_{i=1}^mx^{a_i}$ is reducible. Then there exists a finitely generated subgroup $\Lambda$ of $\mathbf{R}$, containing all $a_i$, such that it is also reducible in $\mathbf{C}[\Lambda]$. Enlarging $\Lambda$ if necessary, we can suppose that $\Lambda$ has a basis $(b_1,\dots,b_k)$, with $k\ge m$, such that for every $i\le m$ we have $a_i=n_ib_i$ for some $n_i\ge 1$. We deduce that $1+\sum_{i=1}^mz_i^{n_i}$ is reducible in $\mathbf{C}[z_1^{\pm 1},\dots,z_k^{\pm 1}]$, and hence in $\mathbf{C}[z_1,\dots,z_k]$ as well.

---

Both sides are clearly false for $m=0,1$. For $m=2$ this is what I claimed in a comment: $1+x^a+x^b$ is irreducible in $D$ (for $(1,a,b)$ linearly independent over $\mathbf{Q}$) iff for all $n,m\ge 1$, $1+x^n+y^k$ is irreducible in $\mathbf{C}[x,y]$. (I'm pretty sure it is, and this ought to be very standard.)

---

Edit: for $m=2$ this is indeed irreducible. Indeed, if $1+x^n+y^k$ were reducible ($n,k\ge 1$), then $1+x^{nk}+y^{nk}$ would be reducible too. So we can suppose $n=k$. Then one can check smoothness of the zero locus of the Fermat curve $x^n+y^n+z^n=0$ (see for instance [this MathSE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1057974/35400)). A hypersurface in $\mathbf{P}^2$ defined by a polynomial is always connected (consequence of Bézout). Hence smoothness implies irreducibility. (A more direct argument is certainly not hard to find). So $D$ indeed has many irreducible elements.

Irreducibility for $m\ge 3$ probably follows from the $m=2$ case.

Comment: Sorry if this is a trivial question: Do we know whether $1 + x^m +y^n$ is irreducible over $C[x,y]$ for all $m,n \ge 1$?. If so then we have found so many elements in $D$ which are irreducible.

Comment: @Infinity_hunter This is the question I explicitly addressed at the end. It's certainly known, and probably standard.

Comment: And finally the answer is yes and I added the argument.

Comment: A more direct argument for the last claim: since $Y^k+1$ only has simple roots in char 0, the irreducibility follows from the Eisenstein criterion.

Comment: @Z.M which Eisenstein criterion are you referring to? the Eisenstein criterion in the Wikipedia page is a criterion for one-variable polynomials over the rationals.

Comment: It is in the section "generalization" of the Wikipedia page, frequently used in the context of totally unramified extensions of DVRs.

Comment: @Z.M thanks, I got it. And it directly applies to for $m\ge 3$, by induction on $m$.